# XSLT sort by two elements; use second if first is repeated

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Basically I have a XML with the following structure and I want to make a XSL Transformation from XML to HTML. The important thing about that is that I want to have a table with all the information about a program sorted by date. The catch is that, if the `date` elements are the same, you should sort by `time`. I have no idea how to pull that off.

```
<scheduling>
  <program channel="FOX" season="9" episode="2">
    <date>2013-06-17</date>
    <time>23:50:00</time>
    <duration>00:45:00</duration>
    <name>CSI</name>
    <resume>Something about a murder, idk...</resume>
  </program >
  ... <!-- program can repeat -->
</scheduling>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [***sort key specification***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-sort-key-specification) allows for multiple `xsl:sort` elements for precisely this use case:

> [Definition: Within a [sort key specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-sort-key-specification), each [**`xsl:sort`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-sort)
>   element defines one sort key component.] The first [**`xsl:sort`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-sort) element
>   specifies the primary component of the sort key specification, the
>   second [**`xsl:sort`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-sort) element specifies the secondary component of the
>   sort key specification and so on.

So, just specify a second `xsl:sort` for the `time` element:

```
<xsl:sort select="date"/>
<xsl:sort select="time"/>
```

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks for the short and concise answer, cheers!